# Iterate a JSON array by a key value in react-native

Tags: json, react-native

Is there anyway to get a value in an object from a json array. I need to get a value from an object based on another value.

I have my code like:

```
export default class StandardComp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
           id: '',
           email: 'abc@gmail.com',
           dataSource: []
        };    
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch(someURL, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({dataSource: responseJson})
            //dunno what to do here
        })
        .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
        })
    }
}
```

My "responseJson" is something like this. Then providing the key value (abc@gmail.com), how could I get the string "abcdef"?

```
[
   {
      "id": "qwerty",
      "email": "cat@gmail.com",
      "name": "cat"
   },
   {
      "id": "abcdef",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "name": "abc"
   }         
   {
      "id": "owowao",
      "email": "dog@gmail.com",
      "name": "dog"
   },
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the element that matches email and return the id.

[array::find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const data = [
   {
      "id": "qwerty",
      "email": "cat@gmail.com",
      "name": "cat"
   },
   {
      "id": "abcdef",
      "email": "abc@gmail.com",
      "name": "abc"
   },       
   {
      "id": "owowao",
      "email": "dog@gmail.com",
      "name": "dog"
   },
];

const findIdByEmail = (data, email) => {
  const el = data.find(el => el.email === email); // Possibly returns `undefined`
  return el && el.id; // so check result is truthy and extract `id`
}

console.log(findIdByEmail(data, 'cat@gmail.com'));
console.log(findIdByEmail(data, 'abc@gmail.com'));
console.log(findIdByEmail(data, 'gibberish'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will depend on how you get the value `abc@gmail.com`.

You'll probably need to pass it in as an argument to `componentDidMount` via a prop? Or extract it to a separate function. It just depends.

Something like this is the most basic way I'd say.

```
const value = responseJson.filter(obj => obj.email === 'abc@gmail.com')[0].id
```

Here it is implemented in your class.

```
export default class StandardComp extends Component {
  ...

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch(someURL, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({ dataSource: responseJson })
        const { email } = this.state
        const value = responseJson.filter(obj => obj.email === email)[0].id

    })
    .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
    })
  }
```

}

Comment: Thank you, I already have the value "abc@gmail.com" stored in this.state.email

Comment: FYI, filter returns an empty array if no elements match filter, so you can't assume there's a zeroth index to return `id` of.